# Error: Could not find or load main class org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG

Tags: java, eclipse, unit-testing, testng

I have written a test suite using TestNG. I have included only one test.java file for my service. I have created the testng.xml file as well. When I run the testng.xml file, I'm getting below error:

```
 Error: Could not find or load main class org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG
```

Please let me know how to fix this. Created the test suite using [this](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/05/spring-testing-support-with-testng.html) link. I ran the suite using [this](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/testng-beginners-guide/9781782166009/ch02s07.html) link.

**Edits:**
My testng.xml looks like:

```
<suite name="TestAll">
  <test name="testService">
    <classes>
       <class name="com.ui.business.service.impl.myservice.test.MyServiceTest"/>
   </classes>
 </test>
 </suite>
```

I have kept the testng.xml in the root folder. The project compiles with Maven. My service class is in com.ui.business.service.impl.myservice package. When I run the testng.xml with "TestNG Suite", I get this error. Please suggest what to do for resolving this classpath issue.

Comment: You need to supply more information in your question. From what I can see it looks like a classpath issue.

Answer (score 22):

This worked for me:

- Right click on your project
- Click on `Properties`
- Click on `TestNG`
- Uncheck `Use Project TestNG jar` box
- Click on `Apply and Close`

Comment: This answer may have worked but is now out of date as this option was removed in https://github.com/cbeust/testng-eclipse/issues/224

Answer (score 6):

I saw this problem when I run testNG in eclipse. I found that it's because the testng jar I included in my build was upgraded from 6.9.9 to 6.9.11. In testng 6.9.11 the class RemoteTestNG is gone. I upgraded by eclipse testng plugin from 6.9.9 to 6.9.11 and the problem is gone.

Answer (score 1):

Please follow the below steps, these worked well for me in Eclipse.

1. Right click on project
2. Go to Build path
3. Go to Configure build path
4. Go to Library
5. Ticked TestNG library and if library not added then add TestNG library by click on Add Library button
6. Go to next tab Order and Export
7. Move TestNG to top
8. Add JRE library as well whcih points to JDK no need to move that up just ticked.
9. Click on Apply.
10. Click on OK.
11. Update project
12. Maven install.
13. Run class as TestNg

Happy Coding!!
Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

In my case I have not added TestNG library to my project after adding it got resolved
Steps:-

1. Right click on project
2. Build path
3. Configure build path
4. Add testNg library
5. apply and close

Answer (score 0):

I can run my tests once I add these dependencies to the project:

```
hamcrest-all-1.3.jar
hamcrest-core-1.3.jar
hamcrest-integration-1.3.jar
selenium-java-2.46.0-srcs.jar
selenium-java-2.46.0.jar
selenium-server-standalone-2.44.0.jar
testng-6.8-dist.jar
testng-6.8.5.jar
testng.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

If you get below error
Error: Unable to initialize main class org.testng.TestNG Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/beust/jcommander/ParameterException

Ans: Add Jcommander-1.48 jar file from Maven.

It will work perfectly fine!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).